# Why do cp, and nocache cp, clog up and slow down/freeze after 2-4 TB, but rsync is effective indefinitely?

Tags: freeze, ram, rsync, cache, cp

Is there a setting I'm missing in CP and nocache CP that frees up resources after each file?

I looked around, and read that cp and nocache cp are MUCH faster, and use more RAM instead of CPU, but not *why*. rsync holds a steady resource usage, while both nocache cp and cp, slowly eat more and more resources until it freezes. Even if it is using RAM, why doesn't it free the RAM/swap/cache in between files? I only have 32GB of RAM and 64GB of swap, but even if I only transfer files that are 2-4 GB, and collectively 2-4TB, it still freezes.

I have assumptions and guesses, but those are bad, and I couldn't find an answer. It's probably obvious to long time users, but I'm pretty new, and I don't want to base my habits on assumptions.

Comment: Any time your reads are faster than your writes, system buffers are used to handle the excess. When they fill up, things drag to a crawl. See answer 995946, and search this site for many more "slow copy" questions. See bug 1208993 and do add yourself to the list.